# MySQL Adding New Slave to Master Master Replication Scheme

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb

I've got two mysql servers, **A** and **B** which are currently set up in a circular, MASTER MASTER replication scheme. I need to add third server to the mix, **C** as a SLAVE to **B** as pictured below:

```
A <---> B
        |
        v
        C
```

I just made an attempt at doing this, but I forgot to take into account the fact that writes that go from **A** to **B** will not make it to **C** without turning on log-slave-updates on **B** being turned on.

*My question:* if I turn log-slave-updates on for **B**, isn't **A** going to pick up on those log entries again execute them a second time, thereby spawning some sort of black hole that could threaten to swallow the planet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the values of server-id are different for each server, no planets will be swallowed.  Not even Pluto.

I suggest you turn on binlog and log_slave_updates on all servers.  Then rebuild C from B (as, I assume, you did once).  Then proceed.  I would not want to try to do it from the current C, which is missing stuff.

Comment: Enabled log_slave_updates on all servers and rebuilt C from B as recommended. All is good now, crisis averted. Thanks!